# Minimum printable font size readable under a microscope

Tags: fonts, print-design, text, print-production, digital-printing

I'm a mechanical engineer about to invest in a new A3 laser printer but won't have the chance to try it out before buying.

It's main function will be to print technical drawings for checking. The largest drawing size I come across is A0, and the minimum font size on said drawing would be 1.8mm.

As I'm scaling A0 to fit A3 that 1.8mm high text will theoretically print out at 0.64mm high.

I've done some research & calcs and think that equates to roughly 2pt text.

I'm struggling to determine whether that size is actually printable on a 600 or 1200 dpi printer (or whether it will just bleed into an unreadable blob).

I'm not interested in "readability" in the conventional sense, which is what all the other similar questions I've found focus on and tend to advise not going much below size 6 text for readability. Those answers don't help me.

I don't mind having to use a magnifying glass on occasion to read this smallest text, which to be fair doesn't happen too often. I just want to know whether a 600 or 1200dpi laser printer *should* be able to print 2pt text that is crisp & clear under the microscope.

Comment: I think one would have to merely test. Every "laser printer" will have a relatively unique tolerance variation. I do not believe this question is answerable without such testing. On my "general office laser printer" a Xerox 350... I can read 2pt type if it's sans serif. All caps is discernible easily with magnification. Lowercase would need someone with younger eyes than I posses. (Ages does terrible things to vision)

Comment: .. and the dot gain of any particular stock may also play a *large* role in maintaining letterforms. (Although for toner and laserprinting that may not be a large factor - it it will be for inkjets, wax, or commercial printing.)

Comment: There's no real way to answer this as it would be dependent on the resolution of the printer, and how well it prints at small sizes, what paper you are using, etc. I think you'd need to test this yourself.

Comment: I'm looking at an Oki c824 which does 1200 x 600 DPI. Or potentially a c844 which does 1200 x 1200. I suspect based on Scott's answer that 2pt all caps text one one of these printers should be discernible?